# In Chrome, How to get audit panel score in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

With Chrome 60 in Dev Tools, there is an [Audits Panel](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/05/devtools-release-notes#lighthouse) with some scores (powered by [Lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/)). The scores at the top for Progressive Web App, Performance, Accessibility, and Best Practices are your aggregate scores for each of those categories.

Do you think, it is possible to access these scores with some `Javascript` code within Chrome?

Comment: I'm afraid i don't have time to try it right now, but the instructions on this page look promising: https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/experimental_devtools_audits

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm going to watch.

Comment: Hummm ;;; "Use the chrome.experimental.devtools.audits API to add new audit categories to the Developer Tools Audit panel.". I don't find API to get Audit data like Lighthouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run Lighthouse from [the command line](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse#using-the-node-cli):

```
npm install -g lighthouse
lighthouse --output=json --output-path=./report.json https://airhorner.com/
```

This will produce a `./report.json` that can be consumed by your script.

---

It's also possible to run Lighthouse from within your node script. It's not described in the docs, but you can check out how [other tools](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse#related-projects) (e.g. webpack-lighthouse-plugin ) are doing it.